# Generating random data using Metal Performance Shaders

Tags: ios, matrix, random, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I am trying to generate some random integer data for my app with the GPU using MPSMatrixRandom, and I have two questions.

1. What is the difference between MPSMatrixRandomMTGP32 and MPSMatrixRandomPhilox?

   I understand that these two shaders use different algorithms, but what are the differences between them? Does the performance or output of these two algorithms differ, and if so, how?
2. What code can you use to implement these shaders?

   I tried to implement them myself, but my app consistently crashes with vague error messages. I'd like to see an example implementation of this being done properly.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: If you're curious about the statistical properties and other characteristics of these different PRNGs, it's not difficult to find papers describing them: [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.4973.pdf) and [here](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150FP/archive/john-salmon/parallel-random.pdf) are good starting points.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample demonstrating how to generate random matrices using these two kernels:

```
import Foundation
import Metal
import MetalPerformanceShaders

let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!

let rows = 8
let columns = 8
let matrixDescriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor(rows: rows,
                                           columns: columns,
                                           rowBytes: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * columns,
                                           dataType: .float32)
let mtMatrix = MPSMatrix(device: device, descriptor: matrixDescriptor)

let phMatrix = MPSMatrix(device: device, descriptor: matrixDescriptor)

let distribution = MPSMatrixRandomDistributionDescriptor.uniformDistributionDescriptor(withMinimum: -1.0, maximum: 1.0)

let mtKernel = MPSMatrixRandomMTGP32(device: device,
                                     destinationDataType: .float32,
                                     seed: 0,
                                     distributionDescriptor: distribution)

let phKernel = MPSMatrixRandomPhilox(device: device,
                                     destinationDataType: .float32,
                                     seed: 0,
                                     distributionDescriptor: distribution)


let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
mtKernel.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, destinationMatrix: mtMatrix)
phKernel.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, destinationMatrix: phMatrix)
#if os(macOS)
mtMatrix.synchronize(on: commandBuffer)
phMatrix.synchronize(on: commandBuffer)
#endif
commandBuffer.commit()

commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted() // Only necessary to ensure GPU->CPU sync for display

print("Mersenne Twister values:")
let mtValues = mtMatrix.data.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
for row in 0..<rows {
    for col in 0..<columns {
        print("\(mtValues[row * columns + col])", terminator: " ")
    }
    print("")
}
print("")

print("Philox values:")
let phValues = phMatrix.data.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
for row in 0..<rows {
    for col in 0..<columns {
        print("\(phValues[row * columns + col])", terminator: " ")
    }
    print("")
}
```

I can't comment on the statistical properties of these generators; I'd refer you to the papers mentioned in the comments.